# could not get the text files that are present in the sub folders of drive

Tags: c#

In my project when I am trying to get the list of all text files in a drive I am getting only the files that are present directly in the drive. I can't get the text files that are present inside the folders of the drive, but would like to. Any ideas ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

namespace listofdirectories
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string str;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["drive"] != null)
            {
               str=Request.QueryString["drive"];
            }

            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(str);
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out all the overloads for `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`.

Comment: See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this GetFiles Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx) that receive also [SearchOption Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx). If you set it to `AllDirectories` it will search the subfolder

So your code should look like this:

```
Directory.GetFiles(str, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: UnAuthorizedAccessException is occuring if i tried this

Comment: If you don't have access to sub folders, how do you want to search them ?